# Best way to query using EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Using LINQ, I am having trouble querying my DbContext in an efficient way.
The database contains 700,000 over entities which have a date and a name and other information.

In my code, I have a new list of objects (which can potentially have 100,000 elements) coming in and I would like to query my database and deduct which information are new entity or which information are existing entities that needs to be updated.

I would like to do it in a very efficient way (with a single query if possible).

This is my code :

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class IncomingInfo
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Modifier
    {
        public void AddOrUpdate(IList<IncomingInfo> info)
        {
            using (var context = new MyDbContext())
            {                 
                //Find the new information 
                //to add as new entities
                IEnumerable<MyEntity> EntitiesToAdd = ??

                //Find the information 
                //to update in existing entities
                IEnumerable<MyEntity> EntitiesToUpdate = ?? 
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me constructing my query? 
Thank you very much.

Edit : 
Sorry I forgot to explain how do I consider two entities equal. 
There are equal if the Date and the Name property are identical.

I first tried to build a predicate using LinqKit PredicateBuilder without much success (encountered the error of parameter too large, had to make multiple queries which took time).

So far the most successful way I found was to implement a LEFT OUTER join and join the incoming list to the DbSet
Which I implemented this way :

```
var values = info.GroupJoin(context.MyEntities,
                    inf => inf.Name + inf.Date.ToString(),
                    ent => ent.Name + ent.Date.ToString(),
                    (inf, ents) => new { Info = inf, Entities = ents })
                 .SelectMany(i => i.Entities.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    (i, ent) => new { i.Info.Name, i.Info.Amount, i.Info.Date, ToBeAdded = ent == null ? true : false });

IEnumerable<MyEntity> EntitiesToAdd = values.Where(i => i.ToBeAdded)
    .Select(i => new MyEntity
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Amount = i.Amount,
        Date = i.Date,
        Name = i.Name,
        Description = null
    }).ToList();
```

My test contains 700,000 entities in database. The incoming info list contains 70,000 items; where 50,000 are existing entities and 20,000 are new entities.
This query takes around 15 seconds to execute which does not seem right to me.

Hopefully this is enough to ask for help. Can someone help me one this ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried already?

Comment: Is it by the `Guid Id` property that you know whether two entities should be considered the same?

Comment: Wow, people are way too fast to just dismiss and close - was in the middle of a response to hopefully answer the question. Now, can't even begin that dialog with the user (at least via an answer, will have to take off-site) :-/ Wish there was an option to contest the hold.

Comment: Here's my answer: http://pastebin.com/pVv6bACW  Basic summary, at 100,000 potential updates, you'll run into EF's limitations and have to do some extra work to keep it fast.

Comment: I edited my question with what I found so far and what is my problem. Hopefully this is enough as a question.

Comment: @HectorTwist Are name and date columns indexed?

Comment: Your `GroupJoin` query is LINQ-to-Objects, i.e. it loads the whole table `context.MyEntities` into memory first and then performs the join in memory. Although it works now, it might not work anymore if your table contains much more than 700000 records or if your system is under memory pressure.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to redesign the solution, and let the client dataset determine if a record is new or needs updating? That way, the update would reduce to a sequential merge/insert operation which can be optimised using Linq Bulk Insert solutions.

Comment: @leniency Thanks for the reply the date range idea was the one I was looking for! Sorry that I can't put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the pastebin response from @Leniency and it covers some of the same stuff I was going to say, like querying a date range and comparing on there. The problem with that method though is that (depending on how those dates are set) it might return all 700K+ records in the database, which would give you the absolute worst performance.

My suggestion is that you analyze your network topology to see how expensive your calls to the database really are. I'm assuming this is running on a (web) server which is receiving these `IncomingInfo` objects from clients. If this server is closely connected to your database server (or on the same machine) then you might be better off not optimizing your calls to the database.

Also, if you have control over the behavior of the clients, you might want to force them to send only like 25 to 100 records with each request. This would make it so that you could deal with them in much more manageable chunks. The client might have to send 100 or more requests to the server (which you could do async so that they get sent ~5 at a time, depending on expected load profiles), but at least it wouldn't be sitting there for 5+ minutes waiting to get a response back from the server for a single request.

BTW, the `GroupJoin` call that you said took 15 seconds probably is having to download all 700K records before doing the join. You see, joins can't be done on objects that don't exist on the same machine, it either has to send all the `IncomingInfo` objects (or at least the Name+Date.ToString() concatenations) to the database, or it has to request all the records from the database before any joins can be done. You would probably have to look at the SQL that is being sent to the database in order to tell which method is being used. But you would probably find that querying the database for matches one at a time would probably be faster than the join in this case.

Hope that helps! ;)

Comment: I do have some "sort" of control over the client. I ll ask them to send only data for one particular date at a time and retrieve the data with a where condition the name and date range. That should work! Thanks.

Comment: @HectorTwist - Without knowing more about the type of data you're working with and how it is used, I can't really give you much more direction as far as how to chunk the data, but I would suggest that you not set an arbitrary limit like "one day at a time" without considering the patterns that are typical for your situation. For example, in some applications, limiting it to one day at a time might end up being one record at a time, but in others, it might be thousands of records at a time. You should discuss with the other programmers to see what the typical patterns would be in this case. ;)